# PHP MySQL not submitting or working

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP and HTML code which should send data from the form to my MySQL database. However, on clicking Submit in the form, the page reloads and nothing happens. No echo or anything. The HTML is in the same file as the PHP file.

**PHP**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $usernamep = $_POST['usernameinput'];
    $passwordp = $_POST['passwordinput'];

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "USERNAMECENSOR";
    $password = "PASSWORDCENSOR";
    $dbname = "database";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password)
        VALUES ('$usernamep', '$passwordp')";
        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);
        echo "Success";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="usernameinput"><br>
    <input type="password" name="passwordinput"><br>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign in">
</form>
```

**Note:** I know this code is currently subject to SQL injection, and the password is not encrypted. It is temporary starting code in an attempt to get it working first.

Comment: What's missing is `name='submit'`

Comment: The fastest way to get it working is to **do it properly the first time**, by the book. Calling [`password_hash`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) so easy it took you more time to write your disclaimer than it would have taken to do that and avoid that liability. Likewise, using prepared statements with placeholder values is not only the safe, correct way of doing things, but it avoids an entire class of bugs relating to SQL syntax, escaping, and errors caused by the query being too hard to read at a glance. Do it properly. Don't make excuses.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. Unless this is purely an academic project, there's literally no reason to write this code. If it is an academic project there's no reason to take short-cuts to get it "working".

Comment: When your page doesn't load, the first thing you need to do is check your error logs. There's usually at least a hint in there as to what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lack the `name` attribute in the `submit` button, add `name="submit"`.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="usernameinput"><br>
    <input type="password" name="passwordinput"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Sign in">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test is wrong. You have no input named "submit" (with attribute name = submit). It should be:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
...
}
```

A broad test like this will not even need a named submit. The HTML form may even be posted on another event using jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In your `PHP` file, you use `isset($_POST['submit'])`. You don't have any `form input` with `name="submit"`. You could make your submit button be

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Sign in">
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to include your php file into the action of the form tag.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
   <input type="text" name="usernameinput"><br>
   <input type="password" name="passwordinput"><br>
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign in">
</form>
```

Comment: That's not needed, if you are using the same PHP file.

Comment: Blank in `action` is shorter that `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>`